# make ArrayList Read only

Tags: java, collections, jakarta-ee, arraylist

In Java, how can you make an `ArrayList` read-only (so that no one can add elements, edit, or delete elements) after initialization?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Pass the `ArrayList` into [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)). It returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. Only use this returned `List`, and never the original `ArrayList`.

Comment: "... and only use the returned List, and never the original `ArrayList`" is a very important addition here! Passing the `ArrayList` to that method doesn't magically change the object. It only returns an unmodifiable wrapper.

Comment: Sometimes you want to keep the original `ArrayList`. This can be a great technique for exposing a `List`-like view of data encapsulated within an object. Modifications to the object will update the `List` view, but the view itself does not accept any modifications.

Comment: `unmodifiableList()` returns a `List` object. Can I cast it back down to `ArrayList` somehow? I get a `ClassCastException` when I try to do this.

Comment: @Pieter the unmodifiable list isn't an extension; it's a delegator.  You can always copy the contents to a new list and modify that, but there is no mechanism provided for modifying the contents on the unmodifiable list, which is kinda the point.

Comment: Note this provides only runtime safety as returned wrapper has mutators which just throw exceptions when called. Its better to use a readonly wrapper which has no mutators to get compile time safety.

Comment: Link appears malformed. Here's the Java 9 doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-

Answer (score 6):

Pass the list object to [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). See the example below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CollDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        List stuff = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "b" });
        List list = new ArrayList(stuff);
        list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        Set set = new HashSet(stuff);
        set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        System.out.println("Collection is read-only now.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use an `ArrayList` in this case?

Maybe it would be better to first populate an `ArrayList` with all of your information, and then convert the `ArrayList` into a final array when the Java program initializes.

Comment: HI Jama, I found Collections.unmodifiableList() this will work the way i wanted. try this method, its straight forward

Comment: well i'll be... that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the collection object to its equivalent unmodifiable function of [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class. The following code shows use of [`unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> objList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        objList.add(4);
        objList.add(5);
        objList.add(6);
        objList.add(7);

        objList = Collections.unmodifiableList(objList);
        System.out.println("List contents " + objList);

        try {
            objList.add(9);
        } catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }
        System.out.println("List contents " + objList);
    }

}
```

same way you can create other collections unmodifiable as well

- [`Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-)
- [`Collections.unmodifiableSet(set)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a convenient way to initialize your ordered immutable List.

```
List<Integer> unmodifiableList = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

> **Unmodifiable Lists** [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)
>
> The List.of and List.copyOf static factory methods provide a
> convenient way to create unmodifiable lists. The List instances
> created by these methods have the following characteristics:
>
> - They are unmodifiable. Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced. Calling any mutator method on the List will always cause
>   UnsupportedOperationException to be thrown. However, if the contained
>   elements are themselves mutable, this may cause the List's contents to
>   appear to change.
> - They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException.
> - They are serializable if all elements are serializable.
> - The order of elements in the list is the same as the order of the provided arguments, or of the elements in the provided array.
> - The lists and their subList views implement the RandomAccess interface.
> - They are value-based. Programmers should treat instances that are equal as interchangeable and should not use them for synchronization,
>   or unpredictable behavior may occur. For example, in a future release,
>   synchronization may fail. Callers should make no assumptions about the
>   identity of the returned instances. Factories are free to create new
>   instances or reuse existing ones.
> - They are serialized as specified on the Serialized Form page.

Note: Though other answers also work and answer the question, I feel like this tidbit adds value to the overall conversation.

Comment: I think this is the way to go now.