# How to prevent element deleting from ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

I want to have an `ArrayList`, and to restrict element delinting as well. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want an `ArrayList` where you cannot ever delete an element from it? Why is this tagged as `magic`?

Comment: I think it's very difficult case. Like a magic for me.

Comment: @Arkasha nothing is the programming world is *magic* (except for good decent optimal readable code from a newcomer, that is magic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a wrapper over `List` interface that doesn't allow removal, just the desired methods:

```
class MyArrayList<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public MyArrayList() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public boolean add(T t) {
        return list.add(t);
    }
    //add other desired methods as well
}
```

Another non recommendable option is to extend from `ArrayList` and override `remove` method(s) to do nothing, but it is not desired because you should not extend from these classes unless it is really needed:

```
public MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean remove() {
        //do nothing...
    }
}
```

Also, you could wrap your current `List` using [`Collections#unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to avoid elements removal (that is a wrapper class like mentioned above except that implements `List`) but note that you cannot add elements either.

Comment: to make it work better i would add implementation of `List` interface, so wrapper could be put in `List<T>` fields and it presence would be transparent.

Comment: @T.G that would depend on OP's design. I don't want to bind the proposed wrapper to `List` interface (note the comment at bottom of my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Create a subclass of ArrayList and override the remove methods.

If you want to forbid all modifications use Collections.unmodifiableList.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ImmutableList class from the google guava library.

BTW: this is a duplciate of: [make ArrayList Read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419353/make-arraylist-read-only)

Comment: The TO wants prevent delete only ... not all actions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class extending ArrayList with will block all remove methods like in example

public class NoDeleteArray extends ArrayList{

```
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return super.remove(o); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
         return false;
    }

}
```

here all remove methods are covering original methods and does nothing. you can also perform some verification to check if object can be deleted from collection for example

```
@Override
public Object remove(int index) {
    MyClass tmp = (MyClass) get(index);
    if (tmp.isDeletable()) {
        return super.remove(index);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```