# What are some of the ways to make an arraylist read-only other than Collections.unmodifiableList()?

Tags: java, collections

What are some of the ways to make an `ArrayList` read-only other than  `Collections.unmodifiableList()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [make ArrayList Read only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419353/make-arraylist-read-only)

Comment: @austinwernli It's not a duplicate. Read the question again.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ seems to be very similar.

Comment: This was asked to me while a job interview. Although I explained to him that it could be done by extending the arraylist class. The interviewer was not convinced.

Comment: Maybe because the conclusion should have been : *it is indeed possible, but in real world application I would use what JDK has, because it already meets the requirement and has been extensively tested*

Comment: So what will happen if I make change to original list? Will changes be made to returned immutable list too ?

Comment: If you use Collections.unmodifiableList, then changes to the backing List will be viewable to consumers of the unmodifiable list (ignoring issues of concurrency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way would be to create a wrapper class, implementing an  List but explicitely returning UnsupportedOperationException for all methods modifying the list. You could just extend AbstractList to have this with less code from you.

And you will obtain a clone of what Collections.unmodifiableList would have given you for free... Doc says : *Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists. Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException*, but less tested so with a higher risk of silent bugs.

My advice is: if it exists, and if it meets your requirements, use it and do not reinvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the array list class and re-implement the methods that change the list to not change the list.

You could also make it final if you know the values ahead of time.

Why would you re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If you can't reinvent something, how can you invent something new?

Answer (score 1):

There is no (practical) way to make an `ArrayList` read only. Wrapping with `Collections.unmodifiableList` creates a new object which is read only. The original `ArrayList` is still mutable.

If you want to build a `List` which is immutable, use guava's [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html).

Comment: So what will happen if I make change to original list? Will changes be made to returned immutable list too ?

Comment: From the [javadoc of immutable list](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)): *Despite the method name, this method attempts to avoid actually copying the data when it is safe to do so. The exact circumstances under which a copy will or will not be performed are undocumented and subject to change.*

Comment: A look at the source code shows that there is special handling when copyOf is called with another ImmutableCollection. Otherwise, a copy of the data is created.